# Inner product space-scalar multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

After reading i am still a bit confused:
(because it's about 2 different fields $\mathbb {C}$ and $\mathbb {R}$ in many explanations i have read is very confusing bcause of the different fields
so i wanted to ask just to be sure i understood)
If the inner product space is over $\mathbb {C}$
$$\langle a,λb\rangle=\overlineλ \langle a,b\rangle$$
and if it is over $\Bbb R$,
$$\langle a,λb\rangle=λ \langle a,b\rangle$$
But in both cases:
$$\langle λa,b\rangle=λ \langle a,b\rangle?$$

Comment: Yes, this follows directly by the definition of an inner product

Comment: and if $λ$ is in the first component so $\lt λa,b\gt=λ \lt a,b\gt$?

Comment: Your question is missing context and doesn't show any effort of your own. In particular, you should do the effort to look up the definition of inner products over real and complex vector spaces. Have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to improve the quality of this and future posts. Please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3988687/edit) your question accordingly, otherwise it will likely attract down votes and get closed.

Comment: I always try to figure it out on my own before I ask,but the page in Wikipedia confused me a bit so I wanted to be sure I understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We say an inner product is linear in its leftmost argument and antilinear in its rightmost one. (In some contexts, such as physicists' use of the [bra-ket notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation) for quantum mechanics, you'll see this convention reversed.) This one-of-each property is not ordinary bilinearity, which is linear in both arguments; instead, [this axiom is called sesquilinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Elementary_properties). But for an inner product space over a self-conjugate scalar field such as $\Bbb R$, $\bar{\lambda}=\lambda$, so for brevity we drop the conjugate for the antilinear argument.

Comment: Thanks it helped me understand